# Best practice iterating DOM and JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, dom

I'm trying to iterate the DOM and a JSON response and add a CSS class to a list item if it is on that JSON or not.

Here's a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/elsevero/Z688d/), can anyone give a hand to do it properly? It seems my approach is not good.

```
    $('#list li').each(function(){
         if ($(this).children().first().next().attr('child-name') == val.name[0] && ($(this).children().first().next().parent().hasClass('available') == false || $(this).children().first().next().parent().hasClass('notavailable') == false)) { 
       $(this).addClass("available");
 } else if (($(this).children().first().next().parent().hasClass('available') == false || $(this).children().first().next().parent().hasClass('notavailable') == false) && val.name[0] != "#N/A") {
       $(this).addClass("notavailable");
}
});
```

So, trying to add a class here:

if is not in the json

```
<li data-id="id-4" client-id="4" class="myclass notavailable"><!-- Conent here --></li>
```

if is in the json

```
<li data-id="id-4" client-id="4" class="myclass available"><!-- Conent here --></li>
```

Comment: I really do not understand your logic, $(this).children().first().next().parent() refers to $(this). But you could do queries like this $('li[child-name="Name 1"]'), http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: @WalterStabosz: $(this) refers to the current list item in each of the jQuery

Comment: Appear `.attr('child-name')` not defined, not an `li` `attribute`, within `HTML` window at jsfiddle ? i.e.g., `<li child-name="abc"></li>`, or `<li data-child-name="abc"></li>` ?

Comment: `i·tin·er·ate : (esp. of a church minister or a judge) travel from place to place to perform one's professional duty.` wat

Comment: There is no JSON in your question??? That's HTML markup!

Comment: I know what $(this) means. What I meant was:  $(this).children().first().next().parent() translates to: "the parent of the sibling of the first element of the children of this element" which is the same element as "this element". Instead of `$(this).children().first().next().parent().hasClass('available')` you can write `$(this).hasClass('available')`. You may want to look into using a [template engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the nesting of the json. It seems you have a json array "clients" of 1 elements I've tried to edit your formatting of the json:

> ```
> var response = 
>     {
>      "clients": [
>       {"0":{"name":"Name 1"},
>        "1":{"name":"Name 2"},
>        "2":{"name":"Name 3"},
>        "3":{"name":"Name 3"}
>       }]
>     };
> ```

(If my interpretation of the json data is correct) - then you can get the data in the following way, preferably constructing an associative object array, which you can then easily reference from your dom loop:

```
var results = new Array();

jQuery.each(response['clients'][0], function(i, val) {
    results[i] = val.name;
});

$('#list li').each(function () {
    if (results[$(this).attr("client-id")] == undefined) {
        $(this).addClass("notavailable");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("available");
    }
});
```

---

And here is a working [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z688d/2/).
(*Changes only to javacript*)

---

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/3Zjw3/9/

Two jQuery plugins which incorporate the functionality of the question specs:

```
$(function () {

    // filters out elements that have existing specified CSS classes
    //
    // @param klass_arg [Array] CSS classes to filter
    // @return selection chain
    $.fn.filter_out_klass = function (klass_arg) {
        // raise unless klass_arg is Array
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(klass_arg) !== '[object Array]') {
            alert('ERROR invalid klass_arg: must be Array');
        }

        // return selections after filter
        // http://api.jquery.com/filter/
        return this.filter(function () {
            $this = $(this);

            // check if any classes defined on elements
            var has_klass = false;
            $.each(klass_arg, function (i, v) {
                if ($this.hasClass(v)) {
                    has_klass = true;
                }
            });
            // return element with no class defined
            return !has_klass;
        });
    };

    // parses response and adds css classes accordingly
    //
    // @param response_arg [Object] like: JSON.parse(json_string)
    // @return selection chain
    $.fn.parse_response = function (response_arg) {
        // raise unless response_arg is Object
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(response_arg) !== '[object Object]') {
            alert('ERROR invalid response_arg: must be Object');
        }

        // return all selections
        // https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/
        return this.map(function () {
            $this = $(this);

            // get client name at hash address from client-id attr
            $name = ((response_arg[$this.attr('client-id')] || {}).name || [])[0];

            // add class 'available' if child element with 'full-name' attribute is found within scope AND child el's 'full-name'-attr equals value
            if ($this.find('[full-name="' + $name + '"]').length) {
                $this.addClass('available');

            // add class 'notavailable' unless specific value: "#N/A"
            } else if ($name !== "#N/A") {
                $this.addClass('notavailable');
            }
            return $this;
        });
    };

    // json string
    $response = '{"clients":{"0":{"name":["#N/A"]},"1":{"name":["Name 2"]},"2":{"name":["Name 3"]},"3":{"name":["Name 3"]}}}';

    // parse json string to hash object and create var with clients node
    $clients = JSON.parse($response).clients;

    // init
    // filter out elements with existing classes from selection , then parse response and perform operations on selection
    $('#list li').filter_out_klass(['available', 'notavailable']).parse_response($clients);
});
```

Comment: This will produce `li` elements which are both 'available' and 'unavailable'. Also, it'd be nice if you could provide an elaborate answer, rather than just paste code.

Comment: @ılǝ good call. fixed code and added comments to elaborate on aspects of processes.